# Does trigonometry need some library

Tags: java

I am trying to run this code but nothing I get..is something wrong with the code or my compiler? can someone point me still new on java

```
public class MathTrigonometricExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double radians = 45.0;

        double sine = Math.sin(radians);
        System.out.println("The Sin of " + radians + " = " + sine);

        double cosine = Math.cos(radians);
        System.out.println("The Cos of " + radians + " = " + cosine);

        double tan = Math.tan(radians);
        System.out.println("The Tan of " + radians + " = " + tan);

        double asine = Math.asin(sine);
        System.out.println("Arcsine of " + sine + " = " + asine);

        double acosine = Math.acos(cosine);
        System.out.println("Arccosine of " + cosine + " = " + acosine);

        double atan = Math.atan(tan);
        System.out.println("Arctangent of " + tan + " = " + atan);

        double sinh = Math.sinh(radians);
        System.out.println("hyperbolic sine of " + radians + " = " + sinh);

        double cosh = Math.cosh(radians);
        System.out.println("hyperbolic cos of " + radians + " = " + cosh);

        double tanh = Math.tanh(radians);
        System.out.println("hyperbolic tan of " + radians + " = " + tanh);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please give more details about what is getting wrong.

Comment: exception in thread "main java.lang.noclssdeffounderror: mathtrygonometric example(wrong name : cin/java/connect/math/mathtrigonometricexample)

Comment: then you might be running it from wrong path

Comment: Have you ever tried to run helloworld in java? Try to comment out all the code and run it again. Odds are good that you have problems launching your app.

Comment: Have you noticed the difference in spelling (mathtr*y*gonometric vs. mathtr*i*gonometric)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tri functions take radians, not degrees. 45.0 looks like degrees, whereas `Math.PI/4` looks like radians.

The answer is, you can use the built in libraries, provided you use radians.  If you need to convert degrees to radian you can sue the following.

```
double degress = 45.0;
double radians = degress * Math.PI / 180;
```

> exception in thread "main java.lang.noclssdeffounderror: mathtrygonometric example(wrong name : cin/java/connect/math/mathtrigonometricexample)

This suggests you are trying to run the wrong class name. When asking a question it is worth including all relevant error messages as we cannot read your mind. ;)

I suggest you use an IDE as this will make editing, compiling and running the program easier.

Comment: That being said, does this cause the problem OP is facing? Just wondering if this is an answer or more of a suggestion/comment.

Comment: While this one is probably helpful (still there is a possibility that OP deliberately set angle to 45 radians), it definitely doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It looks like the answer to the question the OP is going to ask once the program runs and produces some answers.

Comment: I'd say he knows hence the radians variable name. .  Not to mention 45 is a perfectly valid radian value. Sin(45) = .851. Looks can be deceiving.

Comment: @C.Lang It is legal, but you can expect `asin(sin)` to give you 45.

Answer (score 2):

it compiles & runs correctly. are u  sure you have saved source file as "MathTrigonometricExample.java"?

if yes, are u sure u are targetting correct path to run? (to where the .class file resides)